# share distribution question

Tags: business

I just developed a facebook game(mifia like), but the graphics I made are not good, because it is reference with some existing photo, trace with AI, and coloring it.

Therefore, I invited my friend to join me, he is a graphic designer, owns a company with his friend (I know both of them), for the shares, I expect at least 70% for me, and at most 30% for them (both of them want to join).

Therefore, they give me a counter offer, 60% for me and 40% for them, of course, I feel their counter offer is unacceptable because they only build the image in part time, and all the other work just like coding, webhosting...etc, is what I do in full time. Why they said they worth 40% is that they will make a good graphic, they can provide a advertise channel(on local magazine), etc... Actually, I don't think the game need advertisement on local magazine because the game is not target for local...

Please give me some comments on this issue (is the share fair? what is the importance of the image of the game, is it worth more than 30%), or can anyone share the experience on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like this: more share you have -> you more work for the company (idealy, doesnt have to). If they are good designers they could really help you in making beutiful design (and that matters). If they have design company, they propably know something about marketing (maybe more than you, if you are programmer). Thats something to consider if they could bring something good (and unique you dont have) to the project. If it is true, than 40% is not that bad. It should motivate them. And you still hava majority 60%.

And for the last. It is little typical to ask for bigger share and see what happens. Maybe they will be ok with 30%.

Comment: Most of this knowledge i gained by watching Dragons' Den :]. Do not take me too serious. I'm engineer.

Comment: On the contrary, engineers are the people you *should* take seriously. The only thing those buinsess types on dragons den have are MBAs and ruthlessness. Without Artists and Engineers, they are nothing.

Comment: Hi notabene, actually, I'm not really concern on the graphic at this project, because I will re-develop the second version with improvement, most likely, this project just a stepping stone, to help me find out what do I need/notice in the future apps, so, that's why 40% is not worth for them I think, however, after thinking what you say, for long term, I should need a good designer, and if they can really help to generate the revenue, then 40% is absolutely acceptable. You make me figure out, the money is unlimited, it depends on what the way to earn it.

Comment: Hi Luther, I absolutely agree with you, although I didn't watch dragon's den (just figure out what it is :P).

Answer (score 2):

Share percentages and negotiations are something you're going to have to work out with your partners.

That said, this related question might help: [Splitting profit - Equal share vs equity investment (work & money spent = share)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2555/splitting-profit-equal-share-vs-equity-investment-work-money-spent-share)

Comment: Thanks Tetrad, I've read around the link you post, very useful.